# Typescript unexpected "?" when using listrenderItem with extends generic

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

Why I get this error at the end of my extends **>**= ({ item })

Error:

```
(alias) interface IShopsListDataFunction
import IShopsListDataFunction
'?' expected.ts(1005)
```

Code:

```
  const renderItem: ListRenderItem<IShopsListData extends IShopsListDataFunction> = ({ item }) => (
    <View>

    </View>
  )
```

If I remove the extends then it works but I need my IShopsListDataFunction

Comment: Why do you need it here? What behavior are you looking to achieve?

Comment: The error says a `?` is expected, not unexpected. What you have currently is a half-finished [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html).

Comment: That's not a valid declaration. You can't introduce a constraint when you instantiate a generic type, only when you declare one.